# Hiding the Tree View in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Does anyone know how to hide the tree view in pgAdmin 4? I'm referring to the pane to the left of the main window. I've read the documents and didn't find anything on this subject.

Comment: Its 2022, have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can drag the dividing border quite a bit to the left although not over the "servers". 
It isn't a problem for me because opening the query tool starts another tab that completely covers everything

Comment: Yeah I did know that. When you drag it to the left though it still leaves a little space there. When dealing with a 15" screen, I'll take every inch I can get. Especially since I usually have my browser on the other half of the screen